# how to send linux log files to central server and look at them through web interface?

Tags: linux, logging, logrotate

I have a couple of linux servers and `logrotate` and `rsyslog` are taking care of all log files. Now I was wondering whether the following is possible:

- keep log files locally (present)
- send log events to a centralized server (should be possible with logrotate, right?)
- make log events on centralized server browse & searchable

So here are my questions:

1. How do I have setup logrotate and rsyslog (on 'client' and 'server) to accomplish this configuration?
2. does someone know of a good (opensource) web interface that would work with this setup?

**EDIT:**
seems like what I want to accomplish exists for `sysnlog-ng`.  http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/syslog-ng.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are tons of log analysers with web interface for example

- http://www.xpolog.com/
- http://www.splunk.com

etc.

Comment: thanks for the links! I'm primarily interested on how to configure the remote logging of events.

Comment: oh I see, in our production servers we store logs on an NFS drive, but you wanted to store the logs both locally and remotely, so it might not be good for you.